# Where can I find a free shapefile of the Soviet Union | USSR?

Tags: data, russia

Where can I find a free shapefile of the Soviet Union | USSR?

Ideally, I would like to be able to open it straight-away in QGIS.

Comment: Does it have to be a shapefile, could you use a WMS? If so there is: `http://wms.vsegei.ru/VSEGEI_Bedrock_geology2/wms?` and `http://wms.vsegei.ru/VSEGEI_Bedrock_geology/wms?`

Comment: Don't forget that there is an [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the GADM database where you can download Russian boundaries in a variety of formats suitable for QGIS:
http://gadm.org/country

Commercial use of the data is not permitted, however you may download and use freely otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [datasets](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) available from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/). If you select your country (Russian Federation), you will access to data (as raster or vector maps) about:

- Administrative areas;
- Inland waters;
- Roads;
- Railroads;
- Elevation;
- Land cover;
- Population.